# Ошибка ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' внутри requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\Desktop\Ариша.py", line 2, in <module>
    import telebot, os, random, time, calendar, schedule, _datetime, datetime, json, requests, pyglet
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from telebot import apihelper, types, util
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\telebot\apihelper.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .response import HTTPResponse
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._collections import HTTPHeaderDict
  File "C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\_collections.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping, MutableMapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Kirill Dmitrievich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Comment: А что именно непонятно?

Comment: К сожалению, не понял, в чём именно ошибка и как её исправить?

Comment: Какая версия urllib3 установлена? Чувствую что старая.

Answer (score 3):

Классы `Mapping`, `MutableMapping` и некоторые другие начиная с Python 3.3 были перенесены из `collections` в `collections.abc`, но для совместимости оставлены доступными через `collections`. Начиная с Python 3.10 такая возможность импорта убрана.

В Python 3.9 импорт из `collections` работает, но выдает предупреждение:

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, May 23 2022, 21:57:12) 
[GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import Mapping
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 
'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since
Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
>>>
```

Ошибка возникает у вас внутри библиотеки `urllib3`, значит у вас установлена старая версия `urllib3`, не поддерживающая Python 3.10. Нужно обновить `urllib3` до актуальной версии:

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот что вы можете импортировать из collections:

```
import collections

print(dir(collections))
```

```
['ChainMap', 'Counter', 'OrderedDict', 'UserDict', 'UserList', 'UserString', '_Link', '_OrderedDictItemsView', '_OrderedDictKeysView', '_OrderedDictValuesView', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '_chain', '_collections_abc', '_count_elements', '_eq', '_iskeyword', '_itemgetter', '_proxy', '_recursive_repr', '_repeat', '_starmap', '_sys', '_tuplegetter', 'abc', 'defaultdict', 'deque', 'namedtuple']
```

Откуда у вас Mapping, MutableMapping?

Comment: Во-первых, это не ответ. Во-вторых, они там были до 3.10, но их выпилили: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjZHP.png

Answer (score 0):

Надо скачать либо другую библиотеку, либо не импортировать подбиблиотеки, если они в коде не используются.

Проверить, что можно импортировать:

```
print(dir(collections))
```